# Auto Layout: Issues > Update Frames

Tags: xcode, autolayout

In this Auto Layout guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html

it says:

```
To resolve misplacement

Do one of the following:

    Choose Issues > Update Frames.
```

Where do you find the menu item `Issues > Update Frames`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current versions of Xcode, the item is Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Update Frames.

If you ever need to find a menu item in a Mac app, pull down the app's Help menu and type the name of the menu item in the Search field. Highlight one of the hits and it will show you the menu item graphically.

Comment: Nice point. Although it's worth bearing in mind that the relevant menu might not exist in your view. E.g. the Update Frames menu only appears when you're in the Storyboard.